# Nginx Why does my server serve correct content on localhost but not 0.0.0.0

Tags: linux, django, nginx, server

I am trying to get data from my server but if I try from 0.0.0.0/my/api it gives a 400, but if I try from localhost/my/api it gives the content I need. I am using nginx and here is the config file for the server

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/myapp.log;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/myapp;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

Also if I do a netstat I get this for the server

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8080/nginx
```

Why would it only give me the correct content from localhost, and give me 400's from the 0.0.0.0 address? Also this is making it so I can not access the api from an outside machine. Finally I am using gunicorn as a backend server and using nginx to reverse proxy gunicorn.

Comment: `0.0.0.0` is not the IP address of your server. What does `ifconfig` display?

Comment: If you have set `DEBUG=False` in your settings, you'll need to make sure that you've set `ALLOWED_HOSTS` properly. So, if it just contains `'127.0.0.1'`, that could be your issue.

Comment: @csinchok I changed it from `ALLOWED_HOSTS=['localhost']` to `ALLOWED_HOSTS=['0.0.0.0']` and it is still not working.

Comment: @RichardSmith It displays the internal private aws ip x.x.x.x

Comment: When you say you can't get data from `0.0.0.0/my/api`, that might be because that's meta for "all IPs on local network", so it doesn't know where to go. If you're working on localhost, rather use 127.0.0.1

Comment: I figured out what the error was. You need to make sure and set `ALLOWED_HOSTS` in settings.py to the public ip address, and also set `server_name` to the public ip in the nginx server.conf.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your output is the output from `netstat -a` not just `netstat`. Here's a fairly generic result from `netstat -a` on an AWS Ubuntu image:

```
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:hostmon         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:http            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 localhost:domain        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:ssh             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

As one of the commenters noted `0.0.0.0` means "all ip addresses".

Localhost will be represented specifically by the word `localhost` as shown above.

P.S. The `server_name` directive doesn't need to be specified for such a simple `nginx.conf` where you only have one `server` block.

P.P.S. Nice touch turning off logging for favicon in your nginx config!